# Dates and cross joining in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and am running into an issue using cross joins. I have a table, SERVICES, which has start and end dates for a service:

```
SRVC         START          END
Therapy      JAN-1-20       JAN-5-20
Baseball     FEB-15-20      FEB-18-20
```

I need to convert this table to the following:

```
SRVC         DATE
Therapy      JAN-1-20
Therapy      JAN-2-20
...
Therapy      JAN-5-20
Baseball     FEB-15-20
Baseball     FEB-16-20
...
Baseball     FEB-18-20
```

Essentialy, I need one row per day, rather than a date range. My current approach is as follows. I have another table, DATE_TIME, with dates, e.g.

```
CALDR_DT
JAN-1-20
...
DEC-31-20
```

And I am doing the following

```
SELECT s."SRVC", d."CALDR_DT"
FROM SERVICES s
CROSS JOIN DATE_TIME d
WHERE d."CALDR_DT" >= s."START" AND d."CALDR_DT" <= s."END";
```

The problem that I am running into is that this runs painfully slow as in reality, I have a much larger data set. Is there a more efficient way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the execution plan? What indexes exist on the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `DATE_TIME` table and a `JOIN`; instead you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause (recursive `WITH` clause) to generate the rows:

```sql
WITH dates ( srvc, "DATE", "END" ) AS (
  SELECT srvc,
         "START",
         "END"
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT srvc,
         "DATE" + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         "END"
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  "DATE" + INTERVAL '1' DAY <= "END"
)
SELECT srvc, "DATE"
FROM   dates
ORDER BY srvc, "DATE";
```

*(As an aside, don't use `START`, `END` and `DATE` as column names as they are keywords and you will need to surround them in double-quotes, which makes them case-sensitive, to be able to use them in queries.)*

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( SRVC, "START", "END" ) AS
SELECT 'Therapy',  DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Baseball', DATE '2020-02-15', DATE '2020-02-20' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> SRVC     | DATE     
> :------- | :--------
> Baseball | 15-FEB-20
> Baseball | 16-FEB-20
> Baseball | 17-FEB-20
> Baseball | 18-FEB-20
> Baseball | 19-FEB-20
> Baseball | 20-FEB-20
> Therapy  | 01-JAN-20
> Therapy  | 02-JAN-20
> Therapy  | 03-JAN-20
> Therapy  | 04-JAN-20
> Therapy  | 05-JAN-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ffb044d81c1010c1636035a21139c00d)*

Comment: Thanks for the help with this! One quick follow-up, any chance you could tell me how would you amend your solution if END was null for one row and thus the latest date would be the current date? For example, I started my service on July 18 and am still enrolled (i.e. no end date), so I would have four rows (July 18, 19, 20, and 21) with the last number being the date of this posting

Comment: @DJC Instead of `"END"` on line 4, use `COALESCE( "END", SYSDATE )`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but whenever you have both a `CROSS JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause with conditions using elements from both tables, you can rewrite that to use an `INNER JOIN` instead... and *sometimes* the database can then infer a better execution plan.

Again, I can't predict whether that will help in your situation, but when it does help the improvement is usually centered around making better use of **indexes**, where the `CROSS JOIN` ignored a useful index for *filtering* the results and instead chose an index better for *ordering* the results, or that *covers* all of the fields used, because of an assumption that every record in the table would be used.

And speaking of indexes, if this doesn't help that's the next thing to look at. But since we don't know what indexes you already have, anything I suggest here would be a shot in dark.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a separate calendar table here. Instead, use `CONNECT BY LEVEL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SRVC, START_DATE + (LEVEL-1) AS SRVC_DATE
  FROM SERVICES
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (END_DATE - START_DATE)+1
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Given the test data you provided this produces the result

```
SRVC        SRVC_DATE
Baseball    15-FEB-20
Baseball    16-FEB-20
Baseball    17-FEB-20
Baseball    18-FEB-20
Therapy     01-JAN-20
Therapy     02-JAN-20
Therapy     03-JAN-20
Therapy     04-JAN-20
Therapy     05-JAN-20
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=487291dc25f115c30c16eda36978c77c)

Comment: Isn't this is going to be horribly inefficient when you have multiple input rows and large ranges? For each input row it will generate one row when the `LEVEL = 1` and then, at `LEVEL = 2`, the number of rows will be squared since there is no correlation so each `LEVEL = 1` row will be cross correlated to a `LEVEL = 2` row, Then at `LEVEL = 3` the number of rows will be cubed and at each level the number of rows will grow exponentially and then `DISTINCT` will be applied to discard huge numbers of rows. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c151d614d22cc8348b782121add1724)